# Is it possible to make Cognito Form entry data publically available?

Tags: cognito-forms

Can we make the entry records of a form accessible to the public?

For example:

Anyone who wants to register for an event may check out how many have already signed up for this specific event.

Answer (score 1):

I'm a developer with [Cognito Forms](https://www.cognitoforms.com).

No, at the moment entry data can only be accessed by yourself, or a user who has been given access to your Cognito Forms Organization.

I believe that the Customer Portal feature on our Idea Board(No longer public.) might be able to accommodate what you are looking to set up.